# sqlplus 19c varchar2 formatting different fromk 12c

Tags: oracle12c, sqlplus, oracle19c

We are updating our database from 12c to 19c and ovviously the Oracle client.
We do have some jobs which are reporting from sqlplus. We noticed that the varchar2 fields are formatted differently in the new 19c sqlplus.

Simple example:

```
create table tmp_test (test_id varchar2(9) , test_name varchar2(30));
insert into tmp_test (TEST_ID, TEST_NAME) values ('123456789', 'test name 123456789');
insert into tmp_test (TEST_ID, TEST_NAME) values ('987654321', 'test name 987654321');
commit;
```

In 12c, the default formatting is correct:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 16 13:17:44 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Oct 16 2023 13:08:53 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> select * from tmp_test;

TEST_ID   TEST_NAME
--------- ------------------------------
123456789 test name 123456789
987654321 test name 987654321

SQL>
```

but in 19c, for some reason, the formatting is different:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 16 13:25:59 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Oct 16 2023 13:17:44 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.19.0.0.0

SQL> select * from tmp_test;

TEST_ID
------------------------------------
TEST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456789
test name 123456789

987654321
test name 987654321


SQL>
```

Is it possible to revert the formatting to the 12c version without adding the explicit column formatting (like *column test_id format a9*)?

Is this change documented somewhere?

Comment: When you migrated did you change the database character set (or client NLS_LANG) to AL32UTF8? (You might want to look at Oracle Support document 330717.1 if you have access. Or C.4 in 788156.1). Using SQLcl avoids this, but has pros and cons.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

With 19c the maximum length of object names has changed from 30 characters to 128 characters. What you are seeing is the overflow of the 128 characters to a new line.  See for yourself:

```
SQL> desc user_objects;


Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OBJECT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)
```

Comment: your answer is not related to my question.